# Eu queria mandar dois arquivos da minha pasta para meu repositório remoto no github e deu erro depois que eu loguei. O que fazer?

Tags: git, github

usei o comando > **git push --set-upstream origin master** e não deu pra enviar do meu repositório local pro meu repositório remoto, na tela apareceu o seguinte código:

$ git push --set-upstream origin master
To https://github.com/Toni-emmanuel-git/teste.git
 ! [rejected]        master -> master (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Toni-emmanuel-git/teste.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.

Comment: "*Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.*" Viu isso?

Answer (score 1):

Esta mensagem de erro diz que é necessário fazer um pull antes de fazer um push.

```
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind hint: its remote counterpart
```

Esta mensagem diz:

> dica: as atualizações (o comando `git push`) foram rejeitadas porque o
>   seu repositório local está desatualizado em relação ao repositório
>   remoto. (tradução livre)

Para resolver este problema, basta fazer um `git pull origin <branch>` para atualizar o seu repositório local.
Lembrando que para saber branch de trabalho e deve-se utilizar o comando:

```
git branch
```

A branch de trabalho está marcada com (*), a saída deste comando será:

> bugfix3
>
> featureenvioemail
>
> master
>
> * testes

Após a operação acima ser realizada com sucesso, você deve fazer o push novamente.

```
$git push origin master
```

Comment: Entendi, mas em seguida apareceu outro erro. 

There is no tracking information for the current branch.
Please specify which branch you want to merge with.
See git-pull(1) for details.

    git pull <remote> <branch>

If you wish to set tracking information for this branch you can do so with:

    git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/<branch> master

Comment: Você deve utilizar o comando completo. `git pull origin master`

Comment: $ git pull origin master
From https://github.com/T***-*******-git/teste
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
fatal: refusing to merge unrelated histories

Outro erro

Comment: Para resolver este problema é só rodar o comando: `git pull origin master --allow-unrelated-histories`